# Cross-platform addressing of the config file

Tags: python, cross-platform, configuration-files

**Simple case**

I have a Python program that I intend to support on both *nix and Windows systems. The program must be configurable, at least globally. Is there a cross-platform way to address the configuration file?

I.e. I want to write instead of

```
import platform
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    configFilePath = "C:\MyProgram\mainconfig.ini"
else:
    configFilePath = "/etc/myprogram/mainconfig.ini"
```

something along the lines of

```
import configmagic
configFile = configmagic("myprogram", "mainconfig")
```

**A slightly more advanced case**

Can the same be applied to user-specific configuration? I.e. to keep the configuration in `~user/.myprogram/` under Unix, and in `HKEY_LOCAL_USER` registry section under Windows?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200599/whats-the-best-way-to-store-simple-user-settings-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965694/whats-the-official-way-of-storing-settings-for-python-programs

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it's not really a dupe. Those two questions are about the format of the config file, while my question is about its location.

Comment: Don't use ~/.myprogram, use the XDG BaseDir Spec, which defines where you *should* be storing/reading your configurations. (by default, ~/.config/myprogram).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python will allow forward-slash paths on Windows, and `os.path.expanduser` works on Windows also, so you can get a user-specific file path using:

```
config_file = os.path.expanduser("~/foo.ini")
```

if you want to find a .ini in the user's home directory.  I'm not sure how to unify file-based .ini and registry settings.

Comment: Great, and is there a way to solve the first case (global configuration file path)?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `dirspec`. It works in GNU/Linux, Mac OS and Windows.

You can get it from: [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/dirspec/)

Or installing it from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dirspec/)

```
pip install dirspec
```

and in your code use something like:

```
from dirspec.basedir import get_xdg_config_home
config_path = get_xdg_config_home()
```

It's used by Ubuntu One, look at this code example from their documentation: https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/data/u1db/tutorial#storing-and-retrieving-tasks

Answer (score 1):

Current answers provide incomplete solution to your problems (cross-platform + user vs system-wide config).

[confuse library](https://github.com/beetbox/confuse) answers your needs :

> Combine configuration data from multiple sources. Using layering,
>   Confuse allows user-specific configuration to seamlessly override
>   system-wide configuration, which in turn overrides built-in defaults.
>   [...]
>   An in-package config_default.yaml can be used to provide bottom-layer
>   defaults using the same syntax that users will see. A runtime overlay
>   allows the program to programmatically override and add configuration
>   values. Look for configuration files in platform-specific paths. Like
>   $XDG_CONFIG_HOME or ~/.config on Unix; “Application Support” on macOS;
>   %APPDATA% on Windows.