# How to Make a Python Program Recogize first-time use

Tags: python, python-3.x

Everyone!
I'm trying to make a Python 3.3 program recognize that it is the first time the user has used the program. I'm not sure how to proceed or if it's possible.

Comment: You can let the file rewrite itself, or either make a separate buffer file beside the file or in a default OS temp map. In OS X you could make a .plist file in the Library. In *nix you could store a hidden .file in the userfolder. In Windows you could use the Registry. Mostly I'm curious about for what reason you do this. Maybe there is a better way :)

Comment: You need a user preference mechanism.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200599/whats-the-best-way-to-store-simple-user-settings-in-python) for how to build a simple user preference mechanism around `ConfigParser`, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644183/how-to-store-variables-preferences-in-python-for-later-use) for where to put the file (except that it doesn't handle Apple guidelines on OS X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a file in the program directory, and used os.path.exists to make Python recognize the user's first time use.

Answer (score 1):

you need to

Write something somewhere

a> Create A File somewhere

b> write a registry key

c> register use with some website

or probably any other number of ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a text file containing a list of all the users that have used the program and then compare against it during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file in running directory containing a firststartup flag, i used that for a java program, havent used python much.

psuedocode: maybe this will help you find the answer.

1. check if file exists
2. if file does exist assume it is not first time, else, if file does not exist create the file and asume that it is indeed first startup.
3. rest of program.

Answer (score 0):

As bad as sounds, you should probably use a file, like the others are saying. It sounds bad because I am guessing you don't want to write files you don't have to, but in all honesty, it will work out well.

one way you could do it, is have a 'firstuse.txt' in the directory when the user starts it, and when it runs, it deletes that file. That way you can keep things a little cleaner.